# How to get results from odeint function using an array of time values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve the following ODE to get displacement values wrt. time using scipy.integrate.ode. Here is the code I am working with.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

rho_water = 0.9970470
h=7.5
    
def Lor(Z, t,args):
    h = args[0]
    g = args[1]
    Omeg = args[2]
    if Z[1]>0:
        return [Z[1], 1/Z[0] - 1 -Omeg*Z[1] - (Z[1])**2/Z[0]]
    else:
        return [Z[1], 1/Z[0] - 1 -Omeg*Z[1] ]
         
def osc(h=7.5, g=9.80665e2,R=0.05,eta=0.0000889):
    n= (16)*(eta)*((h)**(1/2))
    d=(rho_water)*(R)**2*(g)**(1/2)
    Omeg = (n/d)
    params = (h,g,Omeg)
    t=np.arange(0,500,0.001)
    Z=sp.integrate.odeint(Lor, [0.17, 0.00], t, args=(params,))   
    z=Z[:,0]*h
    n= (16)*(eta)*((h)**(1/2))
    d=(rho_water)*(R)**2*(g)**(1/2)
    Omeg = (n/d)
    params = (h,g,Omeg)
    return z
        
z_0_10=osc(h=7.5, g=9.80665e2,R=0.05,eta=0.0000889)
t=np.arange(0,500,0.001)
```

This code works when I use np.arange and create an array of time values that way but as I have data that I want to fit to the model described by the ODE, I need to solve the ODE over an array of very specific time values, so that I can get displacement values at those times. I want to use those solutions to calculate residuals for my data wrt the model. The array of time values I want to use is:

```
t_0_10=np.array([0.000, 0.067, 0.100, 0.133, 0.167, 0.200, 0.233, 0.267, 0.300, 0.333, 0.367, 0.400, 0.433, 0.467, 0.500, 0.533, 0.567, 0.600, 0.633, 0.667, 0.700, 0.767, 0.800, 0.833, 0.867, 0.900, 0.933, 0.967, 1.000, 1.033, 1.067, 1.133, 1.167, 1.200, 1.233, 1.333, 1.367, 1.400, 1.433, 1.467, 1.500, 1.533, 1.567, 1.600, 1.633, 1.733, 1.767, 1.867, 1.967, 2.000, 2.033, 2.067, 2.100])
```

When I use the array of time values as my argument for time in the ODE instead of using np.arange, I do not get the correct results for displacement anymore. The shape of the graph I plot, is not correct. Here is the code for graph I get when I use np.arange, which is the correct shape. When I use my time values, I get a different graph.

```
graph= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(14,8))
fig, ax1 =graph

ax1.plot(t*(h*1e-2/9.8)**0.5, z_0_10, c='orange', label='Model Solution', marker="o")
ax1.set_ylabel('Fluid level (Z) / cm',fontsize=12)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time Elapsed (t) / s',fontsize=12)
ax1.tick_params(axis="x", labelsize=12)
ax1.set_xlim([0,2.10])
```

How can I fix this issue and get the correct values for displacement using my array of time values? Or, if this is not possible, how can I obtain an array of the correct displacement values at those specific times, while still using np.arange to solve the ODE?

Comment: Please make an example where the time ranges are comparable, the first has time range [0,500] with a ridiculously small time step giving half a million samples, the second has a time range [0,2.1] with more sensible time steps.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you so much for getting back to me. I can see what you mean. I needed to choose that time range only because my data for time is so precise (0.001 seconds), and because I needed the ODE solutions to span 5 minutes. It was actually this code with the higher precision which produced the correct graph. However, I am unable to simply print the array containing the solutions because of the number of samples, as you've said. I'm unsure how to resolve this problem.

Comment: There is a peculiarity of odeint that is not apparent in more modern solver packages. Despite using multistep methods with step size control, which requires interpolation, the output values do not get interpolated from internal nodes. The output times are used as part of the internal nodes while all other parameters remain the same, especially the error tolerances. This can lead to the situation that the output times and their spacing influence the solution. One can reduce that difference by setting tighter error tolerances or using the parameter `hmax`, both reducing the internal step size.